# Output Cache Total Hits not being reflected in IIS performance monitor

Tags: iis, iis-8, outputcache, perfmon

We use output caching profiles in Web.Config like so:

```
    <caching>
        <outputCacheSettings>
            <outputCacheProfiles>
                <clear />
                <add name="CacheHourly" location="Server" duration="3600" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="IsMobile" />
                <add name="CacheDaily" location="Server" duration="86400" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="IsMobile" />
            </outputCacheProfiles>
        </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
```

In `perfmon`, we're seeing 100% misses (no hits) in Output Cache counters. We're basically seeing 0s across the board for Output Cache counters (except misses).

See screenshot below.

[image: Snapshot of performance monitor counters for Output Cache]

The kicker is that I'm fairly sure it's enabled. If I add `enabled="false"` to each output cache profile, and then hit a target page, it will return in 300ms consistently. If I keep them enabled, it will return in 90ms consistently, which isn't super fast, but it's consistently faster than 300ms.

Edit: Am I wrong to think that Output Cache * counters are the correct counters? URI Cache counters seem to have higher hit %, but I thought that was just for IIS URI metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah-hah!

Not to be confused with all the other counters that include Output Cache values, the counter you need to use (in this situation) is the `ASP.NET Applications` counter.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you had gone through these links.
https://serverfault.com/questions/448942/why-is-iis-7-5-flushing-file-cache-very-often.
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching.

It says, you need to use  `<caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">`

But also it says that, this property is by default true, still i would say, give a try!

Regarding performance counter, you are looking into correct metrics.
https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/852720c8-7589-49c3-a9d1-73fdfc9126f0.mspx?mfr=true